# Comparing a string to a number of strings (best Data Structure)

Tags: java, data-structures

I have an an array which I can get the string name from.

```
arr[i].getName();
```

I want a way to compare this to a number of strings I currently have them them in an Enum as follows:

```
public enum BlockManValEnum {

    SecurityID("SecurityID"),
    BlockStatus("BlockStatus"),
    Side("Side"),
    GTBookingInst("GTBookingInst");

    private String name;

    private BlockManValEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }


}
```

I want a way to check the element in the array if it matches one of these attributes then perform extra functionallity if it does not match do not worry about it. I know enum is the total wrong way to store this.

However. The only way I can think around this is to create a map with a String key which will just return a true boolean. (this seems kinda dirty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public enum BlockManValEnum {

    SecurityID("SecurityID"),
    BlockStatus("BlockStatus"),
    Side("Side"),
    GTBookingInst("GTBookingInst");

    private static Set<String> names = new HashSet<String> {{
      for(BlockManValEnum e : BlockManvalEnum.values()) {
         add(e.toString());
      }
    }};

    private static boolean contains(String name) {
      return names.contains(name);
    }

    private String name;

    private BlockManValEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

here is how you could use this:

```
if (BlockManValEnum.contains(arr[i].getName())) {
  // some extra functionality...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a `Map` which maps to a true `Boolean`, you can just use a [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), and check if your element is in  it or not. [and activate the functionality if it is]

Answer (score 1):

You're close... a Map without values is called a Set.  Use a HashSet.  Set has a "boolean contains()" method which is what you want.